# XSL:Choose element cannot have text node children

Tags: xml, xslt

the following XSL file creates an object in a tickettool.
Based on Qualifiers in the Mailsubject it fill in variables

Please have a look

...............................................................................

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:template match="/"
                  name="ExternalTask_Exxeta">
        <BusinessObjectList SchemaVersion="1.0"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="HierarchicalObjects-1.0.xsd">
            <!-- *********************** -->
            <!-- BEGIN: Define Variables -->
            <!-- *********************** -->
            <!-- find the profile link recid of the email sender -->
            <xsl:variable name="profilelink_recid">
                <!-- for each RelatedBusinessObject -->
                <xsl:for-each select="BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject/RelatedBusinessObjectList/RelatedBusinessObject/BusinessObject">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@Name = 'Employee'">
                            <xsl:for-each select="./FieldList/Field">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="@Name = 'RecId'">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- find the profile link category of the email sender -->
            <xsl:variable name="profilelink_cat">
                <!-- for each RelatedBusinessObject -->
                <xsl:for-each select="BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject/RelatedBusinessObjectList/RelatedBusinessObject/BusinessObject">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@Name = 'Employee'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="'Employee'"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- find subject and subjectID -->
            <xsl:variable name="emailSubject"
                          select="BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject/EmailMessage/Subject"/>
            <xsl:variable name="emailSubjectID"
                          select="BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject/EmailMessage/SubjectID"/>
            <!-- set External Task Status according to other tools qualifier -->
            <xsl:variable name="aaStatus">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(normalize-space($emailSubject), '[Completed]')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Completed'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
´                   <xsl:when test="contains(normalize-space($emailSubject), '[Accepted]')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Accepted'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Waiting'"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- Get other tools ticket number -->
            <xsl:variable name="aaVendorIncidentNumber">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(normalize-space($emailSubject), '[Ticket#')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($emailSubject, 0, 21)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- Set Task Resolution if external Task is completed -->
            <xsl:variable name="aaExternalTaskResolution">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($aaStatus, 'Completed')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$emailbody"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- ********************* -->
            <!-- END: Define Variables -->
            <!-- ********************* -->
            <xsl:for-each select="BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject">
                <xsl:element name="BusinessObject">
                    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Task.WorkOrder'"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <!-- Set Transaction as 'Update'.  It will try to update existing record using UniqueKey value, otherwise it will fail. -->
                    <xsl:element name="Transaction">Update</xsl:element>
                    <!--Unique Key List-->
                    <xsl:element name="UniqueKeyList">
                        <xsl:element name="UniqueKey">
                            <xsl:element name="Field">
                                <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="'WorkOrderID'"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <FieldList>
                        <!-- Fields -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="EmailMessage/node()">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="name() = 'SubjectID'">
                                    <xsl:element name="Field">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                                            <xsl:text>WorkOrderID</xsl:text>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Type">System.Int32</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="name() = 'Body'">
                                    <xsl:variable name="emailbody">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:variable>
                                    <xsl:element name="Field">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                                            <xsl:text>Status</xsl:text>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$aaStatus"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                    <xsl:element name="Field">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                                            <xsl:text>VendorIncidentNumber</xsl:text>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$aaVendorIncidentNumber"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                    <xsl:element name="Field">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                                            <xsl:text>BPW_ExternalTaskResolution</xsl:text>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$aaExternalTaskResolution"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                    <!--    <xsl:element name="Field">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:text>Service</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:text>Service Desk</xsl:text>
                                                </xsl:element>
                                                <xsl:element name="Field">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:text>OwnerTeam</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:text>Service Desk</xsl:text>
                                                </xsl:element>
                                                <xsl:element name="Field">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:text>Impact</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:text>Medium</xsl:text>
                                                </xsl:element> 
                                                <xsl:element name="Field">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:text>Urgency</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:text>Low</xsl:text>
                                                </xsl:element>
                                                <xsl:element name="Field">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:text>Status</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:text>Logged</xsl:text>
                                                </xsl:element>
                                                <xsl:element name="Field">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:text>Source</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:text>Email</xsl:text>
                                                </xsl:element> -->
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </FieldList>
                    <!-- Copy the RelatedBusinessObjectList element-->
                    <xsl:element name="RelatedBusinessObjectList">
                        <xsl:for-each select="RelatedBusinessObjectList">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!--</xsl:element> -->
            <!--</xsl:element> -->
        </BusinessObjectList>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Maybe you can find an error. Unfortunately I can't find any clue
Maybe you can find an error. Unfortunately I can't find any clue
Maybe you can find an error. Unfortunately I can't find any clue
Maybe you can find an error. Unfortunately I can't find any clue
Maybe you can find an error. Unfortunately I can't find any clue

Comment: See: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aB9NKX

Comment: P.S Please use a better testing environment instead of asking us to debug your code.